# Including a newly generated file each time in gnu make makefile? Deleting tempory file not working?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile like so:

```
T:=$(shell mktemp)
include ${T}
I:=$(shell rm ${T})

all:
    echo done
```

In theory, `mktemp` should create an empty file and return its name.  The next line should include that file.  The following line should delete it.

When I run it I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `/tmp/tmp.Cwe7kiNBA3'.  Stop.
```

If I comment out the third line like so:

```
T:=$(shell mktemp)
include ${T}
#I:=$(shell rm ${T})

all:
    echo done
```

The Makefile works as expected, but leaves the temporary file behind.

Why doesn't the original example work as expected?

Comment: I want to help you but why do you use the shell command?

Answer (score 0):

Your Makefile seems good without the `include ${T}` command. As described by [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html), the `include` directive is useful to:

> suspend reading the current makefile and read one or more other
>   makefiles before continuing.

So, the following Makefile:

```
T:=$(shell mktemp)
I:=$(shell rm ${T})

all:
    echo done
```

will produce this output and it will not report errors:

```
echo done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Make is trying to [remake](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html) your included Makefile - for example, it works if you replace `include` with `-include` (which doesn't complain when the remake fails). You can fix it by adding an empty recipe for it: `${T}: ;`.

Comment: Just to be clear: `-include` _does_ remake.  It just doesn't complain if the remake fails.